# in mozilla by default scroll thumb and track is not displaying -mac OS

Tags: css, scroll, cross-browser, mozilla

```
.scroll-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}

.scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}

.scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

Here In chrome by default scroll-thumb is coming for a particular div,so it gives an impression to user you have a scroll area  and you can scroll ,but in mozilla since scroll-thumb is not there ,users cant identify that area as scrollable,only when you drag scroll and scroll-thumb is coming.

Since it works in css,answers in css is preferable and am looking in mac.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: send example link with full code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y0zpvfs6/1/

Comment: hence they want to see the scroll part area with scrollbar thumb by default.For safari and chrome we fixed it using webkit,but not working the same in mozilla

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure style scrollbar in Mozilla browser using css is possible or not. But you can style the scrollbar using plugin.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

[scrollbar demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

Comment: without plugin is it possible? explicitly on the jsfiddle i had pasted above using css

Comment: I will check later and let you know.